# Android/Eclipse Package Manager: Generate Java files have different icons?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, class, icons

I am using the Android SDK in Eclipse and I have one simple question. 
 
 Why do the packages/java files in the Generated Java Files have different icons than the src/java files? The Class icons have superscript F's and the folders have a Class icon with superscripted SF's above them? Just curious! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "S" of "SF's" I think it's Source.